# Is there a way I can optimize this query to make it shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I am trying to make the code shorter and simpler. The code is working. I want to take the inner queries to a CTE or temp table to make it shorter. How do I go about this?

```
Create OR REPLACE view piper.v_da_areas_per_site(logistics_id, streams_label, city_id, type) as
SELECT
  dataset.logistics_id,
  dataset.streams_label,
  dataset.city_id,
FROM
  (SELECT
     DISTINCT r.logistics_id,
     r.streams_label,
     r.city_id
  FROM
     top.distributions r
     JOIN (
        SELECT
             distributions. Distribution_id,
             max(distributions.event_time) AS event_time
        FROM
             top. distributions distributions
        WHERE
             distributions.stream_type = 'DA'
             AND distributions. distribution_space = 'DaFilterName'
        GROUP BY
              distributions. distribution_id
    ) m ON r. distribution_id = m. distribution_id
    AND r.event_time = m.event_time
    AND current_date >= r. distribution_start_time
    AND r. distribution_end_time >= current_date
    AND r.stream_type = 'DA'
    AND r. distribution_space = 'DaFilterName'
    AND (
         r.logistics_id IN (
              SELECT
                    DISTINCT dev_class_hub_list.class_hub
              FROM
                     piper.dev_class_hub_list
              WHERE
                     dev_class_hub_list.is_3p = 'N'
        )
    )
   )dataset;
```

Comment: I removed the "performance" tag since you are concerned about simplicity and easier to debug, but not about performance.

Comment: 1) Remove outer query - it is obviously excess. 2) Move all conditions not related to `m` subquery to WHERE. 3) Replace WHERE IN with according WHERE EXISTS and remove DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

These **indexes** may help:

```
distributions:  INDEX(stream_type, distribution_space,
                  distribution_id,  Distribution_id, event_time)
distributions:  INDEX(distribution_id)  -- (unless is PK)
dev_class_hub_list:  INDEX(is_3p,  class_hub)
```

**Try changing**

```
  AND  ( r.logistics_id IN (
            SELECT  DISTINCT dev_class_hub_list.class_hub
                FROM  dev_class_hub_list
                WHERE  dev_class_hub_list.is_3p = 'N' ) )
```

to

```
 AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM dev_class_hub_list AS dchl
                WHERE  dchl.is_3p = 'N'
                  AND  dchl.class_hub = r.logistics_id )
```

The **DISTINCT** may be causing an extra de-dup pass; the `**EXISTS**` is a "semi-join", so it stops when it finds the first one.  The Optimizer *may* turn one of these into the other.  Please  do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;
SHOW WARNINGS;  -- to see the transformations performed
```

**Range** tests like this are notoriously difficult to optimize:

```
      AND  current_date >= r.distribution_start_time
      AND  r.distribution_end_time >= current_date
```

As for **CTE** -- I need to understand what the SELECT is trying to do.

As for **VIEW** -- Views are "syntactic sugar"; they tend to be no better than the equivalent SELECT.  Will you be adding WHERE or other clauses when you SELECT from this VIEW?  They may *or may not* be efficiently folded into the resulting Select.